# Smart Lock Installation by Landlord

Tags: internet

My landlord wants to install smart locks, but use my private WiFi to do so. Upon installation they said they will need access to my router. I know they have a legal basis to install the smart lock. But do they have a legal right to use my personal WiFi account and router to install it?

Comment: will your landlord accept to have you enter the wifi password while he is not observing, thereby keeping your router secure?

Comment: Laws vary around the world. If you would like a specific answer to your question then please add the relevant jurisdiction tag.

Comment: it wouldn't be allowable for a landlord to have control in some countries. In other countries, there is nothing on this matter in their laws. While even Somalia has internet laws (freedom of speech), those are only relevant to the 2% that **have** internet. Even as South Sudan did pass an internet crime law in 2021. those laws vary widely from laws in for example Israel, Russia, or the Dominican Republic! As an odd note: In Eritrea (1.9% have internet), the Landlord's request would require you to be one of about 200 people that have broadband internet. Dial-up costs **200+ $/month** there.